# How to do CSS attribute selector with title~= that has to contain a space?

Tags: css, attributes, css-selectors, title, contains

I have the following selector:

```
.post-link[title~=Corporate]
```

Now I need, instead, to select only elements whose title have the word "Corporate" only at the very beginning, not somewhere else in the title.

So I have two alternatives:

1) create a selector that only checkes at the very beginning of the title and then skip others eventually following or

2) create a selector which can contain a space plus a '|' like:

```
.post-link[title~=Corporate |]
```

because in my case all titles begin with

"Keyword |"

(Corporate | i.g.)

But the css is not working any more when I use:

```
.post-link[title~=Corporate |]
```

I also tried:

```
.post-link[title~=Corporate&nbsp;|]
```

Does not work. How to do this? I cannot find answers with Google.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Now I need, instead, to select only elements whose title have the word "Corporate" only at the very beginning, not somewhere else in the title.

You can use `[title^='Corporate']`:

```css
[title^='Corporate'] {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div title='Corporate foo bar'>Test case 1</div>
<div title='foo Corporate bar'>Test case 2</div>
<div title='Corporate | foobar'>Test case 3</div>
```

**[Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)**:

> **`E[foo^="bar"]`**: an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"

Comment: This did the trick, the other not. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.
`.post-link[title|="Corporate "]`

The `|=` operator matches beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Weird. Doesn’t work in my case. I am checking what could be wrong with my code.

Comment: The difference between `[title^="Sometext"]` and `[title|="Sometext"]` is that the latter needs to be a whole word whereas the first doesn't care about. So only the first one will find `<a href="#" title="Sometexting">` but both will find `<a href="#" title="Sometext-ing">`