# How to construct CSS selector targeting attribute with value containing an ASCII line feed?

Tags: css, css-selectors, linefeed

Suppose you have html that contains the following:

```
<div title="aaa"></div>
<div title="example"></div>
<div title="exam
ple"></div> // the enter key has been pressed after the substring "exam" in the title attribute
```

I understand that if I wanted to select for the second and third divs I could use the following CSS:

```
div[title^="exam"] {....}
```

But how would the third div be selected exclusively? I have Codepenned the following selectors:

```
div[title="exam\nple"] {...}
div[title="exam\x0Aple"] {...} // line feed ---> hex
div[title="exam\u000Aple"] {...} // line feed ---> unicode
```

None of these worked as I intended (i.e., selecting the third div exclusively - no elements were selected for at all).

*How would one select in this case for an attribute (`title` here) with a value which contains a line feed using **title=** ?* (and not **title^=** or **title|=**, etc.)

Note - I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358874/how-can-i-use-a-carriage-return-in-a-html-tooltip) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360096/how-to-do-css-attribute-selector-with-title-that-has-to-contain-a-space) post for background info but I'm still not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Characters and case - escaped characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#escaped-characters),

> backslash escapes allow authors to refer to characters they cannot
>   easily put in a document. In this case, the backslash is followed by
>   at most six hexadecimal digits (0..9A..F), which stand for the ISO
>   10646 character with that number, which must not be zero.

A [new line character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm) has the code U+000A. So in CSS you can escape it as `\a`  or `\00000a`.

```css
div[title="exam\a ple"] { font-size: 2em; color: green;}
```

```html
<div title="aaa">aaa</div>
<div title="example">example</div>
<div title="exam
ple">exam[newline]ple</div>
```

Comment: Just tested this - yes, this did the trick. Thank you for your help

Comment: BTW - white space between the "\a" and "ple" seems unnecessary

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob That's because the following char (`p`) is not a hexadecimal digit. But IMO it's better to make clear the end of the number, either by adding a space or providing exactly 6 hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can just use `div[title^="exam\00000a"]` and it works

[Check Here on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjaJjA)

Comment: Please read my post - this selects both the second and third divs

Comment: The question already mentions `div[title^="exam"]` and says this is not what it wants.